# How to explain that ZFS' snapshot reports 'WRITTEN' as 4.26GB, but the transfer size is actually 31.4GB?

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

When I run this query on a dataset

```
zfs list -d 1 -t all -o name,used,refer,written,compressratio sfg-backup/mx
```

I see the following stats:

```bash
zfs list -d 1 -t all -o name,used,refer,written,compressratio sfg-backup/mx
NAME                                           USED     REFER  WRITTEN  RATIO
sfg-backup/mx                                  300G      276G        0  1.80x
sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-15_23:15:00_UTC  4.04G      275G     275G  1.28x
...
sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-21_01:15:00_UTC     0B      276G        0  1.28x
sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-21_02:15:00_UTC     0B      276G    4.26G  1.28x
sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-21_03:15:00_UTC     0B      276G        0  1.28x
```

However, when I run a backup, that has the last snapshot as `madcow_2023-04-21_01:15:00_UTC` the size of the backup is not 4.26GB but 31.4GB

```bash
syncoid --no-sync-snap 10.0.1.2:sfg-backup/mx work/sfg/mx
NEWEST SNAPSHOT: madcow_2023-04-21_03:15:00_UTC
Sending incremental sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-21_01:15:00_UTC ... madcow_2023-04-21_03:15:00_UTC (~ 31.4 GB):
31.5GiB 0:03:16 [ 163MiB/s] [==================================================================================================>] 100%
```

adding `-c` for compression brings the size to 4.3G (these are slighly different snapshots, but with more of less the same content.

```
zfs send -nv -c -I sfg-backup/mx@madcow\_2023-04-24\_00:15:00\_UTC sfg-backup/mx@madcow\_2023-04-24\_03:15:00\_UTC
send from @madcow_2023-04-24_00:15:00_UTC to sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-24_01:15:00_UTC estimated size is 215M
send from @madcow_2023-04-24_01:15:00_UTC to sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-24_02:15:00_UTC estimated size is 4.09G
send from @madcow_2023-04-24_02:15:00_UTC to sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-24_03:15:00_UTC estimated size is 624B
total estimated size is 4.30G

# without -c flag:
zfs send -nv  -I sfg-backup/mx@madcow\_2023-04-24\_00:15:00\_UTC sfg-backup/mx@madcow\_2023-04-24\_03:15:00\_UTC
send from @madcow_2023-04-24_00:15:00_UTC to sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-24_01:15:00_UTC estimated size is 216M
send from @madcow_2023-04-24_01:15:00_UTC to sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-24_02:15:00_UTC estimated size is 31.3G
send from @madcow_2023-04-24_02:15:00_UTC to sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-24_03:15:00_UTC estimated size is 624B
total estimated size is 31.5G
```

Can you help me understand what can cause this large discrepancy in sizes? Why reported by ZFS compression is 1.28 and transfer compression is 31.5/4.3=7.3?

Comment: `zfs get compressratio sfg-backup/mx`

Comment: @ewwhite, good point, I added compress ratio to the question

Comment: Please show `compressratio` for snapshots from `madcow_2023-04-21_01:15:00_UTC` to `madcow_2023-04-21_03:15:00_UTC`

Comment: I added compressratio to the snapshots @shodanshok

Comment: Can you show the output of `zfs send -nv -I sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-21_01:15:00_UTC sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-21_03:15:00_UTC`

Comment: don't post responses as comment, edit the question instead please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WRITTEN` shows *compressed* data actually written to the dataset/snapshot. Between `sfg-backup/mx@madcow_2023-04-21_01:15:00_UTC` and `madcow_2023-04-21_03:15:00_UTC` you wrote highly compressible data on top of previous incompressible data, without de-referencing the entire file.

I suppose you have some big file which can be randomly overwritten (ie: virtual disk image files, databases, etc), and it just happened that you wrote 32G of raw data which became 4G of compressed data.

`zfs send -c` sends the compressed records as they are, transferring only the compressed 4G delta. On the other hand, `zfs send` (without `-c`) uncompresses the on-disk data, expanding them to the full 32G size.

Comment: thank you for the reply @shodankshok. So how to explain the difference in compression reported by ZFS (1.28x) and the difference in sizes (7.3x) between compressed `send` and uncompressed `send`?

Comment: 1.28x is the `compressratio` of the *entire referenced data (276G)*. 1.28x276=353, so there is ample margin to expand your 4.3G into >30G